# Scrapy spider closes prematurely after yield request inside start_requests function

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have no idea at all how to do this.  Basically I want to run a database insert before running the scraping program.  I have tried to do this by placing a yield request at the top of the start_requests() function, like so, except what happens is the pipline executes and the scrape terminates instead of actually going to the next line in start_requests.

```
def start_requests(self):
    db = MyDatabase()

    link = "http://alexanderwhite.se/"
    item = PopulateListingAvItem()
    self.start_urls.append(link)
    yield Request(link, callback=self.listing_av_populate, meta={'item': item}, priority=300)

    #program terminates successfully completing the above request, but I need it to continue to the next line

    query1 = "SELECT listing_id FROM listing_availability WHERE availability=1"
    listing_ids = db.query(query1)


    for lid in listing_ids:
        query2 = "SELECT url from listings where listing_id="+str(lid['listing_id'])
        self.start_urls.append( db.query(query2)[0]['url'] )


    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, self.parse, priority=1)
```

Comment: It makes sense to me that the start_requests function would end with the Yield call, and then scrapy would continue on to the pipeline.  Why don't you include the database query content inside the callback function?  Or have the insert function call another function for the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not obvious and could be helpful to others.  In this case, when you need to perform an insert query before doing any scraping, you can use yield item, followed by the rest of your start_url generator code inside the first callback function as suggested by ice13berg.   The whole key is to use "yield item".

I don't quite understand why it works but it does, correctly executing the insert with the item, and using the result of the insert for the next select queries.

```
def listing_av_populate(self,response):
    db = MyDatabase()
    item = response.meta['item']    
    item['update_bid_av'] = 3

    yield item

    query1 = "SELECT listing_id FROM listing_availability WHERE availability=1"
    listing_ids = db.query(query1)


    for lid in listing_ids:
        query2 = "SELECT url from listings where listing_id="+str(lid['listing_id'])
        self.start_urls.append( db.query(query2)[0]['url'] )


    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, self.parse, priority=1)


def start_requests(self):

    link = "http://alexanderwhite.se/"
    item = PopulateListingAvItem()
    yield Request(link, callback=self.listing_av_populate, meta={'item': item}, priority=300)
```